# How many signatures can a signing key (safely) produce

Tags: signature

Given an AES key, there is a limit (of about $2^{64}$ blocks) of how much plaintext it is safe to encrypt with the key.

Is there a similar limit for how many signatures it is safe to produce with a signing key (such as RSA, DSA, or ECDSA)?

(I would also be interested if there is similar limit for asymmetric encryptions.)